# Viewing exported env vars with elixir

Tags: environment-variables, elixir

I understand how you set an environment variable using elixir.

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id
```

Okay that works, but what if I'm not confident that I typed everything correct and I want to check what the value is? How can I do this with Elixir?

Comment: i'm not sure i follow... you could add all your env variables to a .env file on your project (make sure to not commit them) and you can see those values anytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage the following function: [`System.get_env/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#get_env/1).